# Microsoft Teams configurable tab "team"-scope not working

Tags: microsoft-teams

I create a new teams app by using the Teams Apps generator. I selected configurable tab -> scope "team" and "groupchat":

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "id": "dfbf6890-7268-11ea-ad8e-3f4752fcafa2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "packageName": "test4",
  "developer": {
    "name": "dev",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "test4",
    "full": "test4"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/smensocloudTab/config.html",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{HOSTNAME}}"
  ]
}
```

But when i side load the app to test in teams, i only see "Add to a chat" but not "Add to a team".
See the attached Screenshots (frist is how it is, second how i want it).
How can i fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if your manifest is properly created. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) for manifest creation.

Comment: I added the full manifest. I can't see anything wrong here and i did not change what the generator created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it,

if anyone ever has the same problem.
Remove the empty defintions:

```
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": []
```

That solved the case for us.